# When is the wrong time to use a Collections.synchronizedList vs. a List?

Tags: java, list, synchronized

Other than a (minor?) performance hit, why would I use a regular List instead of a Collections.synchronizedList vs. a List?

The project I'm working on is under 10k entries, so *I* don't care, but if someone (maybe me) chooses to sub-class this, I need to document the behavior.

Besides performance (over 100k entries), why would I not synchronize?

That is, what penalty do I incur for using a synchronizedList?  How bad is it?  For my current application, it's not an issue.  If it is a cheap addition, why not?

Comment: The reason you mentioned should be enough to convince you not to use a `SynchronizedList`, if it's not necessary.

Comment: These may be removed by the JIT at runtime, but synchronization actions require process context switches in order to use system calls to acquire and release system mutexes.

Comment: If I understand the feedback I've received (Thanks!), synchronization of a list *is* expensive, even for a short list.

As a side question, it seems odd that this action requires a context switch.  Is this an implementation issue?  It seems like a system mutex is overkill for this sort of action.

In any event, the message I received is don't use a synchronized list unless it is *required*.

@Stephen C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Other than a (minor?) performance hit ...

In fact, if the list is shared between threads, the performance hit of using a simple synchronized list (versus something more appropriate) could be a *large* performance hit, depending on what you are doing.  The synchronized operations could become a concurrency bottleneck, reducing the application to the performance of a single core.

Simple "black and white" rules are not sufficient when designing a multi-threaded application ... or a reusable library that needs to be thread-safe and also performant in multi-threaded applications.

---

> That is, what penalty do I incur for using a synchronizedList? How bad is it? For my current application, it's not an issue. If it is a cheap addition, why not?

The synchronized list class uses primitive object locking (mutexes).

- If the lock is uncontended, this is cheap; maybe 5 or 10 instructions each time you acquire and release the lock.  However, the ovehead *may* depends on whether there was *previous* contention on the lock.  (Some locking schemes cause an object lock to be "inflated" the first time that contention occurs ...)
- If the lock is contended, then it is more expensive because this will typically involve the blocked thread being de-scheduled and rescheduled ... and context switch overheads.  There is another JVM-level implementation approach involving "spin locking", but that entails the blocked thread testing the lock object in a tight loop.
- If the lock is held for a long time (e.g. in list.contains ... for a long list.) then that typically increases the *probablility* of contention.

Comment: By "single core", I assume you mean a thread of execution. (nes pas?).  Like he "Battle of Thermopylae".

Please tell me about your "something more appropriate"?

Comment: Good point, it is tempting to assume that Java's `synchronized` collections are necessarily performant in concurrent thread access, however there are collections with much better multi thread access performance, like the concurrent collections.

Comment: No.  I mean hardware core.  A typical modern computer (like your laptop or desktop) has 2, 4, 8 or even more cores that can execute multiple threads in parallel.  (High end systems can have hundreds of cores ...)

Comment: *"Please tell me about your "something more appropriate"?"* - There are whole books on this subject ... but you can start by looking at the javadocs for the collection classes in `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: Stephen C.: Let's pretend for a moment that I'm running a VAX 11/780... that right, I upgraded from the 11/750.

All smart-ass aside, I think what I'm hearing is that "use single thread as far as you can", and "let sub-classes multi-thread as they may".

Has this notion captured the moment?

Comment: Well, not really.  The core issues is whether you want to implement your application as multi-threaded (or whether it is inherently multi-threaded by nature, etc).  If you need multi-threading, now or in the future, then design accordingly.  If your application is single threaded, then making your data structures synchronized doesn't achieve anything, and it 1) incurs a performance overhead and 2) makes your code more complex, less readable, and harder to maintain.

Comment: The other point is that it could be difficult to create a thread-safe subclass of a class that is not thread-safe.  It depends on the API.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't need the synchronization, or when you aren't deluding yourself that a synchronized list is thread-safe even when iterating, which it isn't.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  So the synchronization is write oriented?  The reader is left in flux?

Comment: @ErikBennett - I don't understand your comment.  How could synchronization be "write oriented"?  What do you mean?

Comment: I guess I was asking if reader (A) is moving along and updater (B) is adding/removing;  Is this what you meant by "deluding yourself that a synchronized list is thread-safe even when iterating, which it isn't".  What are better options?